# missing value from json object when writing if condition it's througing an error

Tags: json, node.js

my JSON Object is varies based on some conditins. when i am trying to access the value from json object when it is not present it's througing an error message saying that value is not defined. How to avoid such kind of situations??

IntentSlots: '{"cnumberslot":{"name":"cnumberslot","value":"C186206"}}' - condition works perfectly.

IntentSlots: '{"cnumberslot":{"name":"cnumberslot"}}' } - throws an error.

my condition is like below,

if(IntentSlots.cnumberslot.value !== ""){
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the condition if the property is not available add an empty value to that property because if u leave it empty it will throw that error.

or use different if condition

```
if(IntentSlots.hasOwnProperty('value') && IntentSlots.cnumberslot.value !== ""){ }
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, it may work if i add null value or empty value for value. But when how the second one works? has OwnProperty is an predefined library routine??